# Spring Data JPA and Jackson JsonIdentity weirdness with one-to-many relationships

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jackson, spring-data-jpa

I'm observing some weird jackson behavior which I need help with. I have the following two one-to-many relationships in my simple library application:

- `Book` contains a list of `BookCopy`
- `Library` contains a list of `BookCopy`

The idea is that a single book may have many copies, and each library owns copies of books (and not books directly). That said, here's the relevant snippet of my code:

`Book` class:

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Book {
    //.. rest omitted
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book")
    private List<BookCopy> bookCopies;
}
```

`Library` class:

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Library {
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "library")
private List<BookCopy> bookCopies;
}
```

`BookCopy` class:

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class BookCopy {
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "book_id")
private Book book;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "library_id")
private Library library;
}
```

Now, when I add a book and a library, without the copies, things work fine. When I add a book-copy object though, I get some seriously strange output from the serialized version of `bookRepository.findAll()`.

This is a sample json I'm POST-ing to add a book copy:

```
{
  "book": {
  "id": 1
  },
 "library": {
  "id": 4
 }
```

}

.. and things are persisted perfectly into the DB (postgres). However, when I retrieve all books, here's a sample weird JSON I get (snipped for brevity):

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Effective Java",
    "bookCopies": [
      {
        "id": 5,
        "book": 1,
        "library": {
          "id": 3 // ...
        }
      }
  },
  2
]
```

Note the last part - the weird `2` sticks out of nowhere - in a list of book objects. Am I doing something seriously wrong - or is this some jackson bug I'm hitting?

Comment: This is not valid JSON: the curly and rectangle brackets don't match. Please show the real JSON you get. But anyway, you're using http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIdentityInfo.html. Read the javadoc. It says: *In practice this is done by serializing the first instance as full object and object identity, and other references to the object as reference values*. It's probably what is happening here.

Comment: Here's an example of the `getAll` on the library repository: https://justpaste.it/1a1ek - the code is available at https://github.com/ragebiswas/bookworm/tree/master/src/main/java/net/rajorshi/bookworm/internal/domain. It still looks to me like I'm hitting some bug. Note the last integer in the output.

Comment: That looks completely correct to me. The library 24 has already been serialized as a full object before in the tree, so its ID if just used later, as documented.

Comment: Oh -- I see - didn't think of it this way. This makes parsing on the client side slightly non-trivial. Thank you @JBNizet - please post as a reply so I can accept your answer.